# React 18 and Suspense problem (worked in older versions)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-suspense

In my React app with react router I used to define routes like this:

```
   <Route exact path={Paths.landing} component={Awaiting(starWars)} />
```

with Await helper defined like this:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

function Awaiting<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
    return (props: T) => (
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
            <Component {...props} />
        </Suspense>
    );
}
export default Awaiting;
```

And while this worked perfectly in 17.xx version it does not in 18, namely Awaiting throws errors:

```
'Suspense' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Suspense'?

Cannot find name 'fallback'
Operator '>' cannot be applied to types '{ null: any; }' and 'number'
```

and few others generally indicating that syntax is wrong.

After reading article
https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/07/29/react-18-alpha-behavior-changes-in-suspense

I tried:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

function Awaiting<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
    return (props: T) => (
        <Suspense fallback={<><h1>"Loading"</h1> </>}>
            <Component {...props} />
        </Suspense>
    );
}
export default Awaiting;
```

But it is still not OK.
What is wrong here, what should be the code like?

Comment: is your file `.tsx` or `.jsx`

Comment: yes, you are right - it should be tsx

Answer (score 0):

OK, after changing file type .ts => .tsx

and slight type modifications it works like this:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

function Awaiting<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
    return (props: React.PropsWithChildren<T>) => (
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
            <Component {...props} />
        </Suspense>
    );
}
export default Awaiting;
```